# jfrog artifactory-maven-plugin doesn't deploy modules pom when using mvn profile

Tags: maven, pom.xml, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have maven multi-project, And I want to use jfrog artifactory-maven-plugin  to connect my CI-bulds to the artifacts in my artifactory. But when I'm running "mvn deploy" with profile, the pom.xml of my modules doesn't deployed (only the patent pom) and the artifacts number in my artifactory doesn't updated every build.

jfrog artifactory-maven-plugin in the parent pom:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
      <inherited>false</inherited>
      <executions>
         <execution>
            <id>build-info</id>
            <goals>
               <goal>publish</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
               <artifactory>
                  <includeEnvVars>true</includeEnvVars>
                  <envVarsExcludePatterns>*password*,*secret*,*key*,*token*,*passphrase*</envVarsExcludePatterns>
                  <timeoutSec>60</timeoutSec>
               </artifactory>
               <publisher>
                  <contextUrl>http://my_artifactory_url</contextUrl>
                  <username>userName</username>
                  <password>password</password>
                  <includePatterns>*.pom *.jar *.war</includePatterns>                                
                  <filterExcludedArtifactsFromBuild>false</filterExcludedArtifactsFromBuild>
                  <repoKey>libs-release-local</repoKey>
                  <snapshotRepoKey>libs-snapshot-local</snapshotRepoKey>
               </publisher>
               <buildInfo>
                  <buildName>${buildName}</buildName>
                  <buildNumber>${buildNumber}</buildNumber>
                  <buildUrl>${buildUrl}</buildUrl>
               </buildInfo>
               <licenses>
                  <autoDiscover>true</autoDiscover>
                  <includePublishedArtifacts>true</includePublishedArtifacts>
                  <runChecks>true</runChecks>
                  <scopes>compile,runtime</scopes>
               </licenses>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

my profile:

```
<profile>
   <id>noCompilation</id>
      <build>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
     </build>
</profile>
```